# Machine learning for android app

Tags: accord.net

I am making an app for android which you will take a picture of a bird from wild and app will be connected with its databse with a lots of pictures and informations about bird species. I am vondering if android camera can recognize such photos?...is this machine learning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Android Camera will just click photos. It cannot recognise anything. This could be Machine learning if you use Artificial Neural Network and train the system with a training set containing images of the birds form wild.